# How to hide the HTML grid's button inside of Kendo grid MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 2 grids one is Kendo and one is HTML. 
First I am calling Kendo grid MVC and 2nd I am calling HTML grid with 3 buttons.
I want to hide the HTML's button inside of Kendo grid column based on condition.

**Edit:**

I have one grid and column

```
columns
    .Bound(o => o.PatientName)
    .Title("Member Name")
    .ClientTemplate( "# if (!cond) { #" + 
        "<a id='test' style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='ClickFire(#:PatientId #)'>#: PatientName#</a>" + 
        "# } else { #" + 
        "#: PatientName#" + "# } #" );
```

So based on condition I want to hide one button as well but button is not available in this grid; it exists in another grid which is HTML.

Comment: I have one grid and column    --- columns.Bound(o => o.PatientName).Title("Member Name").ClientTemplate(
                                 "# if (!cond) { #" + "<a  id='test'  style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='ClickFire(#:PatientId #)'>#: PatientName#</a>" +
                 "# } else { #" +
                                 "#: PatientName#" +
                                 "# } #"
                                 ); --- so based on cond I want to hid one button as well but button is not available in this grid it is exist in another grid which is html

Comment: okkk ?!! can you somewhat provide images that describe what should happen ?

Comment: why didn't `$('#button').hide()` work ?

Comment: Firoza, add question-related info in the question, not in the comments. You can edit your question and add info anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code, further explanation or the conditions under which you want to hide buttons.

To hide a button or elementin general using JQuery, use:

`$("#button").hide();`

where "#button" is the id assigned to your button. You can replace this with pretty much anything and be as precise as you would like - using "div.thisClass" uses all divs with the class "thisClass" assigned to them, for example.

You could call this function inside of a triggered event, such as

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#button").hide();
}
```

for calling it as soon as the page has loaded (including graphics).

If you want a more detailed answer, however, please provide more details and clarification.

Comment: I prefer waiting for OP to edit the question , add the necessary details before answering

Comment: @niceman that's perfectly fine and I agree with you in general - however, I'm a fan of not telling people the exact answer fitting to their problem; instead, I encourage everyone to use an example, adapt it to their needs and thus learn something off of it instead of copy pasting something and being happy it works.

Comment: columns.Bound(o => o.PatientName).Title("Member Name").ClientTemplate(
                                 "# if (!cond) { #" + "<a  id='test'  style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='ClickFire(#:PatientId #)'>#: PatientName#</a>" +
                 "# } else { #" +
                                 "#: PatientName#" +
                                 "# } #"
                                 ); ---- here I want to add one more line like this '$(".clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan").hide()' ** Is it possible and .clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan this button is not from same grid it is from html grid

Comment: @FirozaShaikh Please add your code example and further explanation(s) to your main question.

`$(".clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan").hide()` will hide any element with the class "clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan" attached to it, regardless if it's from another grid, as long as the element is existing when calling the "hide"-method.

Comment: by the way `#button` isn't a class, it's an id :)

Comment: columns.Bound(o => o.PatientName).Title("Member Name").ClientTemplate(
                                 "# if (!IsSensitiveDiagnosis) { #" + "<a  id='test'  style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='ClickFire(#:PatientId #)'>#: PatientName#</a>" +
                                 //'$(".clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan").hide()'+
                                     "# } else { #" +
                                 "#: PatientName#" +
                                 "# } #"
                                 );   -- Can u see the commented code? I want to use it .Is it possible in kendo grid

Comment: $(".clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan").hide() this is html grid's button and I want to hide it from kendo grid beased on condition like how we are adding hyperlink and removing hyperlink

Comment: I think this information is enough.. Is it? or u want more clarity?

Comment: I am using button's class not id to hide the button like $(".clsBtnReqRejViewCarePlan").hide()

Comment: @FirozaShaikh I was talking to N.M

Comment: oh so sorry                                      -- -

Comment: @FirozaShaikh I'm not that familiar with Kendo, but the function I showed you is JQuery-Syntax. You would have to import JQuery and wrap the function call(s) in `<script>`-tags or use standard JavaScript-Syntax. Alternatively, you could add a class to your css file which sets `display: none` and add the class to your button when your condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely clear on the final solution for you based on the question but I have created a sample [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ujorA) which hopefully will help you get to the final answer.

Personally I prefer potentially complex templating to be pulled out of the initial declaration of the column and split into either an external template or a mixture of javascript and templating.

So rather than using your current templating solution I have altered this to simply:

```
 .ClientTemplate("#=getTemplatedItem(data)#");
```

So all I am doing is pointing the template to a javascript function.

```
 function getTemplatedItem(data){
       var model = ''; 
        var template = $('#modTemplate').html(); 
        
        model = kendo.template(template); 
        
        return model(data); 
      };
```

This function then simply calls an external html template and loads the data **the data for the row** and then returns back the outputted html.

```
 <script id="modTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div class='customer-photo' style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#=data.CustomerID#.jpg);'>
  </div>
  <div class='customer-name'>
  #:data.ContactName#
  </div>
  
  <div>
  #if(data.ContactTitle !== 'Owner'){#
  <button class='k-button k-primary' type="button" onClick="alert('#:data.ContactName#')"> 
  #:data.ContactTitle#
  </button>
  
  #}else{#
  
  
  #}#
  </div>
  
  
  </script>
```

So this template takes your code and allows you to mix and match javascript with html and generates the required output. In this sample I am simply testing for if the person's contact title is `Owner` and if they are then don't render the button. This could be expanded out to include what ever logic you require.

If you need anything else let me know but without seeing an example of what it is you want to do then it is difficult to give you a more complete solution.

**Note: this is just using one of the kendo demo's and moding it slightly to show this example**